# How to specify gateway address for static IP in OpenWRT /etc/config/network

Tags: ip, openwrt, gateway

I see the following example for static IP config:

```
config interface 'lan'
        option type 'bridge'
        option ifname 'eth0.1'
        option proto 'static'
        option netmask '255.255.255.0'
        option ip6assign '60'
        option ipaddr '192.168.1.1'
```

from [here](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/basic-networking#example_network_configuration).

I see IP and netmask, but where is the gateway?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too intimate with openwrt configuration, but "gateway" is a property of routing, not of interfaces.

I know this usually gets combined into one task "set up a network connection", and that's fine, logically, for end user computers, but for a router, it doesnt work like that – a default gateway applies to all networking software, not to just one interface.